# Advanced Mysql over Wordpress Custom Fields

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have many custom fields - price,weight etc............

Now I am trying to create a custom search based on that and I want to search by minimum & maximum...Somehow I am unable to create the exact query.........Will appreciate someone's help on this..

Here is the query I am trying

```
$where = "";
if ( isset( $_POST['pricemin']) && $_POST['pricemin'] != "" ) {
    $pricemin = $_POST['pricemin'];
    $where .= " and (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where  meta_key='list_price' and meta_value > ".$pricemin.$order.") ";
}
if ( isset( $_POST['pricemax']) && $_POST['pricemax'] != "" ) {
    $pricemax = $_POST['pricemax'];
    $where .= " and (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where  meta_key='list_price' and meta_value < ".$pricemax.$order.") ";
}
```

and here is the final line..

```
"SELECT * from wp_posts where ID IN (select 1 from wp_postmeta ".$where.")"
```

Any suggestions on UNION,INTERSECT etc or the best way to do it..........Thanks

Actually mysql Between solves half of my problem......I can write it all as

```
if ( isset( $_POST['pricemin'] ) && $_POST['pricemin'] != "" ) {
    $pricemin = $_POST['pricemin'];
    $wherep1= "  (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where  meta_key='list_price' and meta_value > ".$pricemin.$order.") ";
}
if ( isset( $_POST['pricemax'] ) && $_POST['pricemax'] != "" ) {
    $pricemax = $_POST['pricemax'];
    $wherep1 = " (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where  meta_key='list_price' and meta_value < ".$pricemax.$order.") ";
}
if ( isset($_POST['pricemin'] ) && $_POST['pricemin'] != "" && isset( $_POST['pricemax'] ) && $_POST['pricemax'] != "" ) {
    $pricemin = $_POST['pricemin'];
    $pricemax = $_POST['pricemax'];
    $wherep1 = " (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where  meta_key='list_price' and meta_value BETWEEN ".$pricemin." and ".$pricemax ." ".$order.") ";
}
```

But then I want to search over weight,height too..............

So,something like Intersect could have helped me ..But I see that MYSQL doesn't support INTERSECT........So,the question remains how to rewrite the query

A INTERSECT B INTERSECT C INTERSECT D in mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the Answer.....

```
SELECT * from wp_posts where ID IN ( (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key='list_price' and meta_value BETWEEN 1 and 1229000 ) ) and id in (SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key='weight' and meta_value BETWEEN 20 and 200 )
```

Using Between & And Clauses !

Answer (score 0):

Modify your final query to this:

```
"SELECT * from wp_posts where ID IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta ".$where.")"
```